# How to access a TextBlock within a ListBox with C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, listbox

For most of you, this might be an easy question, but I am a C# beginner (coming from VB) and would like to progam a Windows Phone App.

The question is: How can I access the `TextBlock` "LineOne" from code to change its width? For the page title, it works perfect with this (on orientation change):

`this.PageTitle.Text = "Portrait";`

However, something like this:

`this.LineOne.width= "50";`

won't work. 
Why?

My XAML looks like this (almost the default data bound app from Visual Studio Express):

```
    <!--TitlePanel -->
    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="Bundesliga" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel -->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <ListBox x:Name="MainListBox" Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectionChanged="MainListBox_SelectionChanged">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel x:Name="ListboxPanel" Margin="0,0,0,17" Width="432" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="LineOne" Text="{Binding LineOne}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource  PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Width="40" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your ListBox can have multiple entries, therefore there's no one TextBlock called 'LineOne'. I can think of a hack that would let you change the width of all the textblocks in the listbox - bind the width in the datatemplate to the width of some control on your form. But I'll leave it to the WPF experts to give the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have to access the TextBlocks inside the listbox.
Something like:

```
TextBlock textblock = ListboxPanel.Items[index] as TextBlock;
textblock.Width = 50
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IEnumerable<TextBlock> listtb = ListboxPanel.Items.TypeOf<TextBlock>();
```

Answer (score 0):

The name can't be resolved as belonging to `this` as it belongs to the datatemplate. You can't refer to an item within a template (from outside that template) as there could be multiple items with that name and names must be unique.

If you are trying to change the style of the selected item you will likely find a better solution to be to use different visual states to represent this.

If you are trying to access a property which relates to the bound viewmodel you can cast the sender to the type of the viewmodel and access it's properties directly.